# Where is Adya-Kali mentioned?

Tags: tantra, kali, vamachara

In addition to the Mahanirvana Tantra and Taradipika Tantra, what other tantric texts talk about the so-called Adya-Kali?

Comment: Afa Ik Adya devi is mentioned in Brahmayamala & Mahakala Samhita too.

Comment: Yes, I've heard about it too. Please provide the necessary citations.

Comment: https://greenmesg.org/stotras/kali/adya_stotram.php this famous Adya stotram is from Brahmayamala.

Comment: Well, yes, it seems to be true.